# C++ Preprocessor - working previously, now not

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin, c-preprocessor

I laid aside some code for 4 or 5 years & picked it up again today.

I have not changed the code, but in the intervening years I have upgraded Netbeans and uninstalled Cygwin 32 bit, and today installed Cygwin 64 bit.

The major preprocessor macros are defined in the Netbeans project, not int the code. Some seem to be ok, but some are giving me error like this:

```
g++    -c -g -DBUILD_VERSION_MAJOR\ \ \(0\) -DBUILD_VERSION_MINOR\ \(1\) -DDEFAULT_FREED_MEMORY_VALUE\ \(0xA5\) -DDEFAULT_UNITIALIZED_MEMORY_VALUE\ \(0XCC\) -DDO_TRACING -DTESTING -DTRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH\ 17 -DTRACE_FILE_NAME -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/1472/cppUnitMain.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/1472/cppUnitMain.o ../cppUnitMain.cpp
<command-line>:0:26: error: expected ']' before numeric constant
../testing/buffer_pool/../../system/h/buffer_pool_private.h:92:16: note: in expansion of macro 'TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH'
  char fileName[TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH];
```

but when I evaluate `TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH]` it says `17`.

The file with the error does include the file which declares the macro (else, I imagine, NetBeans would not have evaluated it).

If I try to `#define TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH 17` just before the line giving the problem I still get the same error, but also a warning

```
In file included from ../testing/buffer_pool/test_buffer_pool.h:37:0,
                 from ../cppUnitMain.cpp:46:
../testing/buffer_pool/../../system/h/buffer_pool_private.h:79:0: warning: "TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH 17
 ^
```

Worked before. Doesn't work now. No code change. Same NetBeans project, but probably upgraded by NetBeans. Cygwin 64 instead of Cygwin 32.

Any ideas?

---

[Update]  I ran GCC with the -E option to run the pr-processor only and that line said `char fileName[17];`.  Most strange!

As to the command line, I have no control as it is generated by NetBeans.

I also tried changing to `TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH=17` instead of `TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH 17` in the project options, but that did not work, and it previously worked (a few years ago) with space instead of `=`.

Comment: Preprocess your file to see how macro are expanded. I think it is the "-E" option.

Comment: The only thing I found pause on in this was "The file with the error does include the file which declares the macro". If it is as you describe, there is no "file" that declares the macro; it is done via compiler switch, so I'm not sure what that statement means. (or I read the question wrong and seriously shouldn't be posting this early in the morning).

Comment: Indeed I see a `-DTRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH\ 17` in the original post. Since I know nothing about g++: Does the backslash mean anything?

Comment: Try replacing `-DTRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH\ 17` with `-DTRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH=17`

Comment: Does the definition of TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH in the header file match the definition in the project? (The major preprocessor macros are defined in the Netbeans project) and (The file with the error does include the file which declares the macro) could lead to a conflict.

Comment: The preprocessor is doing what you expect: it's replacing `TRACE_FILENAME_LENGTH` with a numeric constant. The compiler message is claiming that it wants a `]` instead of a `17`. The problem is likely somewhere else.